Unauthorized Errors - NextJS using NextAuth and Cognito + HeyApi
NextJS 14+ App router - with NextAuth for authentication with Amazon Cognito as the identity provider.
The application integrates with an API generated by HeyApi which uses the OpenAPI specification. This is where I try to set the authToken.
I am facing an issue where the access token, once refreshed, is not consistently applied to API requests. Roughly two-thirds of the time, API requests fail with an "Unauthorized" error because they are sent without the updated token.
Link to the OpenAPI generator we use: https://heyapi.vercel.app/openapi-ts/get-started.html
When the user's token is refreshed, I update the accessToken to be used in the OpenAPI configurator as follows:
Root layout for the auth protected dashboard
  useEffect(() => {
    OpenAPI.TOKEN = session?.access_token as string; //This is sometimes undefined???
  }, [session]);

Heres how the [...nextauth]/route is setup
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }: any) {
      if (account) {
        // Save the access token and refresh token in the JWT on initial login
        return {
          access_token: account.access_token,
          expires_at: account.expires_at,
          refresh_token: account.refresh_token,
        };
      } else if (Date.now() < token.expires_at * 1000) {
        // If the access token has not expired yet, return it
        console.log("not expired");
        return token;
      } else {
        console.log("expired, refreshing...");
        try {
          // token expired
          const response = await fetch(process.env.COGNITO_TOKEN_URL ?? "", {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            body: new URLSearchParams({
              client_id: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID ?? "",
              grant_type: "refresh_token",

              refresh_token: token.refresh_token,
            }),
            method: "POST",
            cache: "no-cache",
          });

          const tokens: CognitoTokenSet = await response.json();

          if (!response.ok) throw tokens;
          OpenAPI.TOKEN = tokens.access_token as string;
          return {
            ...token, // Keep the previous token properties
            access_token: tokens.access_token,
            expires_at: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000 + tokens.expires_in),
            // Fall back to old refresh token, but note that
            // many providers may only allow using a refresh token once.
            refresh_token: token.refresh_token,
          };
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error refreshing access token", error);
          // The error property will be used client-side to handle the refresh token error
          return {
            ...token,
            error: "RefreshAccessTokenError" as const,
          };
        }
      }
    },

    async session({ session, token }: any) {
      if (session) {
        session = Object.assign({}, session, {
          access_token: token.access_token,
          refresh_token: token.refresh_token,
          expires_at: token.expires_at,
          error: token.error,
        });

        OpenAPI.TOKEN = session.access_token as string;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

Any help is highly appreciated! 
